# Compile times and run times concept

Tags: swift

I am trying to understand behind the scenes periods when writing codes to clicking on iPhone Screen. I made some enumerations to make question clear.

**Time 1**: I am writing codes on Xcode ( compile time )

---

**Time 2**: There is a syntax error or I forgot the override keyword ( compiler works on behind the
scene and say hey you have an error, fix this)

---

**Time 3**: I fixed the error, looks like there is no error. ( compile time )

---

**Time 4**: I pushed the Command + B and no error ( compile time - swift compiler converted my front end code to assembly code for my CPU and RAM

---

**Time 5**: Command R ( Run time )

---

**Time 6**: My app works fine. ( Run time )

Rather than pointing stack on compile time and heap on run time ( value types on stack - reference types on heap ) ,

- Could you explain me what happens in these time periods which I enumerated ?
  For example at the Time 3 - compile time. My machine or program know where String values or my custom methods ( value types ) knows where they will be put in memory exactly ? Yes it will be allocated in stack but as soon as I wrote code swift compiler convert to machine code and putting to the RAM stack side or I have some missing point ?
- My second question which is related to first one, in Run time all value types memory allocated for stack ?

I almost read all resources so I have some background but I could not imagine what is going on exactly when I divide this time slots. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to resume a little :
Time 1 to Time 3 are editor time. What happens there is that the compiler is run only to check for syntax, variable initialization, parameters validity,... This is just ´precompilation’

Time 4 is compile time where machine code is generated, link who’s all needed libraries and frameworks.

Time 5 is installation, start (eventually debugger connection to running process)

Time 6 is application is running and interacting with user

Comment: Editor time and precompile, Thanks. So when I build all stack memory allocated for value types ?